# Connection reset(WebDriver Exception) in appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

Hi all I got an exception name webdriverException: Connection reset on some elements during my IOS script running, I am using appium v1.8.0. It's is not happening every-time but some time on many elements, When I catch this exception and try to use same action it works.

**All the capabilities given below:**

```
`cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.4");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 7 Plus");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.SUPPORTS_ALERTS,true);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.CLEAR_SYSTEM_FILES,true);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.SUPPORTS_FINDING_BY_CSS,true);
cap.setCapability ( "useNewWDA", true);
cap.setCapability ("webviewConnectRetries", "25" );
cap.setCapability( "usePrebuiltWDA", true );
cap.setCapability("simpleIsVisibleCheck",false);
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,"120");`
```

**Exception given below:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b325d5', time: '2017-03-10 09:10:29 +0000'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxxx.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1cf3:2859:a854:82a0%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.4', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteTimeouts.implicitlyWait(RemoteWebDriver.java:835)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.changeImplicitlyWaitTimeOut(AppiumElementLocator.java:81)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.waitFor(AppiumElementLocator.java:87)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElements(AppiumElementLocator.java:133)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfAListOfElements.intercept(InterceptorOfAListOfElements.java:50)
    at $java.util.ArrayList$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b5855c01.get(<generated>)
    at Main.Regression.HomeIconSelection(Regression.java:899)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.doExecute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:162)
    ... 34 more
```

Can anyone help me to tackle this issue?

Comment: what appium-java-client version you are using? Wll be good to add driver initialisation and exact code where you face this error

Comment: I am using 5.0.0 BETA6

Comment: driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

Comment: And Important, i am using page factory framework with testNG.It happens randomly, suppose I tried to click on tab bar element and sometime it goes through some time connection reset, I used try catch and same element works in catch statement e.g. try {
            objTabBarElement.MyAccountBar.click();
        } 
           
        } catch (WebDriverException e) {

          
            objTabBarElement.MyAccountBar.click();

        }

Comment: Update client library to 6.0.0, that may help. Don't set selenium library explicitly, Appium already has been one

Comment: I updated and got this: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/DeploymentException

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "apache")` before driver init.